# Переносное значение

Tags: лексика, недопустимая-метка

Помогите подобрать предложение со словом "поступить" в переносном значении.

Answer (score 1):

Книга поступила в продажу.

Поступить в значении "дойти, прибыть по назначению"

Поступить - совершить поступок - прямое значение.

Comment: А интересно, почему поступить - это прямое значение, ведь глагол "ступить" в первую очередь обозначает пространственное перемещение (куда?), а значение (как:?) больше похоже на переносное: хорошо, плохо, правильно - это уже оценка из области этики.

Answer (score 0):

Мой друг поступил правильно: выбрал престижный университет и хорошую специальность.

**ПОСТУПИТЬ**, 1. как Совершить по отношению к кому-л. действие, оцениваемое каким-л. образом; действовать каким-л. образом в отношении кого-л. **П. правильно,** хорошо, плохо. 2. Устроиться куда-л., зачислиться, включиться в состав кого-л. **П. в школу, в университет**. П. на работу. П. учиться.